# How to return the lowest non nan value for each row if present

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like the following:

```
        import pandas as pd
        import numpy as np
        data = [[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan], [np.nan, '1987-09-01', np.nan], [np.nan, '1987-09-01', '1988-09-01']]
        df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['1', '2', '3'])
```

#### My goal is the following:

- For the first row, I would like to return the **nan value**
- For the second row, I would like to return the **date**
- For the third row, I would like to return the **oldest date** ('1987-09-01') and also return the **index** of the row that contained two values (in this case 2)

#### First attempt

```
       df.stack().groupby(level = 0).first()
```

But this results in only returning the first date that it encounters for each row, and drops the full nan rows.

Thanks in advance for helping out. If there are any questions, please let me know!

Comment: use `dropna=false` when using stack `df.stack(dropna=False).groupby(level = 0).first()` , this would not drop the full nan rows, however, it cannot find the minimum date as dates are string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Convert columns to datetimes and get oldest date per row by `min`:

```
s = df.apply(pd.to_datetime).min(axis=1)
print (s)
0          NaT
1   1987-09-01
2   1987-09-01
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Looking at the answer I feel I had no clue how min works precisely